# Issue installing Tiny_tds on OS X 10.8.4

Tags: ruby, bundler, chef-infra

It always returns the following error :

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...

ERROR: Error installing tiny_tds:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

freetds is missing.
```

I've tried several methods found here to install freetds, but they all fail.

Any solution or workaround greatly appreciated!

---

### Edit

Fixed it by installing 'Homebrew', and running

```
brew install freetds
```

then

```
gem install tiny_tds -v '0.5.1'
```

Comment: Great! Thanks for telling us how you fixed it. Please add an answer for your question and mark it as the answer: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Answer (score 3):

(Copying your own answer)

Fixed it by installing 'Homebrew', and running

```
brew install freetds
```

then

```
gem install tiny_tds -v '0.5.1'
```